# Find out Chat session is through VPN connection

Tags: c#, java, vpn

Is there a way to find out whether the current chat session is happening through a VPN connection programatically (using either C# or Java) ?

I don't have access to network tools to do a R&D ( first of all not sure whether it can be tracked live), hence i haven't tried anything.

Any help/pointers/directions will of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it would depend on how the VPN is set up.

If the VPN is connected using a software endpoint then it will normally have a simulated network adaptor that you could most likely find the name of (the hardware drivers display name not the connection name) and compare it to a list of known VPN network adaptors.

If the VPN is connected using a hardware endpoint like a firewall or other dedicated network device then there may be no way to tell without some sort of man in the middle hardware approach.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Your answer thrown light on what i thought to be a dark area. :)